# How to create CaffeineCache object using Java?

Tags: java, object, caffeine

I am trying to use Caffeine cache. How to create the object for the Caffeine cache using Java? I am not using any Spring for now in my project.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Caffeine's [official repository](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) and [wiki](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki), Caffeine is a high performance Java 8 based caching library providing a near optimal hit rate. And it is inspired by [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava).

Because Caffeine is an in-memory cache it is quite simple to instantiate a cache object.

For example:

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .maximumSize(10_000)
    .expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .refreshAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build(key -> createExpensiveGraph(key));
```

1. Lookup an entry, or null if not found:

   ```
   Graph graph = graphs.getIfPresent(key);
   ```
2. Lookup and compute an entry if absent, or null if not computable:

   `graph = graphs.get(key, k -> createExpensiveGraph(key));`

   Note: `createExpensiveGraph(key)` may be a DB getter or an actual computed graph.
3. Insert or update an entry:

   ```
   graphs.put(key, graph);
   ```
4. Remove an entry:

   ```
   graphs.invalidate(key);
   ```

**EDIT**:
Thanks to @BenManes's suggestion, I'm adding the dependency:

Edit your `pom.xml` and add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i created a sample spring application , and in the java based configuration i created below Cache object 
cache =  Caffeine.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(24, TimeUnit.HOURS).build(); ,  tried to autowire this in service class like below
@Autowire
private Cache cache;   but getting error that at least 1 Bean of type Cache must defined .    Why this exception is getting ? i defined that type bean , any help please .

Comment: @Bravo did you add the dependency (jar) to your build? For Spring you might want to look at their [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-cache) project.

Comment: @Bravo You could look at one of the [examples](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/tree/master/examples) for a self contained usage. We can add more based on suggestions. Spring isn't required and I'm not familiar with it enough to advise beyond their sample caching project.

Comment: @Bravo All you need is `private final Cache<Key, Graph> graphs = Caffeine.newBuilder()....;`. This initializes the field and **you're done**... there's nothing to `@Autowire`. If you need to use the cache from multiple places, then you can let Spring manage the class containing it.